# Looking for proper method to analyse a data sample (n=200) with a huge amount of variables (800)

Tags: hypothesis-testing, correlation, multivariate-analysis

I have a data sample (approx 200) from a population of about 60 000 people. There are around 800 columns/variables in my data (the reason being that I had a few questions for which I applied a multiple choice arrays and the data just exploded). I'm trying to find out whether a certain score that was automatically calculated during taking the survey (it is a numerical value from 18-90) has some correlation/causation with other variables (most of which are qualitative and when imported to my statistical package show as "string" ones). It will also be interesting to be able to control for age, income level, gender of the participants (information that I also have). What methods of analysis do you think I can rely on?

Comment: Sorry but software related topics are off-topic on this site (check https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Btw, if you are starting to learn new software and are interested in open-source one, I'd recommend rather trying R -- it is much more advanced than PSPP, so it'd be harder to learn it, but the future benefits would be greater. Moreover, R has very good documentation as compared to limited PSPP manuals.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. My only issue is that I have like a week to analyse this data.

Comment: Questions solely about how software works are
[off-topic](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here, but
you may have a real statistical question buried here. 
You may want to edit your question to clarify the underlying 
statistical issue. You may find that when you understand 
the statistical concepts involved, the software-specific elements are 
self-evident or at least easy to get from the documentation.

Comment: I'll try editing it then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I would do:

1. Convert all variables that are stored as a string into numeric format. For instance, if there is a multiple choice question with four possible answers, then create four dummy indicators (binary flags :0/1) for that question.
2. Make sure you don't have any missing data. In most cases, based on your description, I would replace missing values with zeros.
3. Perform a **correlation analysis** to study the correlation between (a) all of the input variables -- e.g., answers, age, gender -- and (b) your outcome variable, i.e., the "score". The correlation coefficients will help you understand which input variables are strongly correlated with the score.
4. The next step is to perform a **regression analysis** on your data. Once the best model is built, you would study the composition of the model (which variables made it to the final model, and what are their standardized coefficients, etc.) to make inferences about the relationships in this sample. For instance, if you have age in the final model, and also the answer for question #5, then you can make a statement about how much question #5 influences the score after controlling for age.

Comment: I would add a step 5: perform a [dimension reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensionality_reduction)

Comment: Sure, good point. I assumed that dimentionality reduction (and variable selection) would be a part of the regression analysis step.

Comment: I'm only afraid this might take a looooong time. Is there an easy way to decode the string information into numerical? Also, my issue is that a lot of the data has no values. Let's give an example from the many array questions: There was one where I asked which (of 13 given activites) were performed on the previous day and how much attention was paid each (choosing between 1-3). This means that sometimes for a variable, I will have people giving it 3 points, other times - 2 and some - none. I wonder how to introduce this into the analysis.

Comment: @vishal I was not quite sure you included it as PCA or LDA may be grouped with correlation analysis, and feature selection with regression analysis

Comment: @ManuH, I wouldn't recommend PCA or LDA in this case, because that wouldn't help clearly understand the true relationships with the **original** independent variables (which is what he's after).

Comment: @SimeonVasilev, (1) You have only ~200 records, so in terms of *processing time*, this shouldn't take too long. (2) If data is sparse, you can consider combining some of the categories. For instance, in your example, are there any logical groupings of activities? (3) It would be also interesting to capture *how many* activities each respondent selected.

Comment: (1) You are right. I found a way to decode this information with PSPP for each variable, so that should make it much easier than the way I imagined it - doing it for each cell by hand (2) I'm going to post here an image that shows the array with the questions about time use: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByN1eZfkbZ9RY1ppajJZRkJFYXM. I hope you can imagine how the data distribution will look, but you are right - it is very sparse indeed. (3) Not sure how to do that either in an easy way.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not familiar with **PSPP**, so I can't help you with how to exactly do these steps using that software. There's probably a separate forum somewhere for software-specific questions. Please upvote or accept my answer above if you found it useful, and let us know if you have any additional questions.

Comment: @Vishal I did find it incredibly useful, but I can't upvote, because I just registered and my reputation score is very low. I ticked it, though ;) I will go to the software section to ask for assistance also. I think you practically answered my question as well as you can with the information provided by a layman as me :)

Comment: Glad I could help! You may find software-specific help in the PSPP manual -- see Section #11 in the following link: http://www.gnu.org/software/pspp/manual/pspp.html#GET-DATA-_002fTYPE_003dPSQL

Comment: Ok, now I have another question. I don't really understand to concept of dummy variables. I guess I can't just take (for example) one gender and assign it a random number (let's say male=1, female =2, transgender male =3, transgender male =4, etc.)?

Comment: For your example, I'd create three dummy variables: MALE, FEMALE, and OTHER (assuming that there are not many records in the other category). The MALE variable, for instance, would be equal to 1 for respondents who are males, and 0 otherwise. Hope this is possible to do in PSPP.

Comment: I need to create a variable for each qualitative answer that I have for each question, right?. So for example, if I want to introduce gender, I can' t do just a Gender tab, where Male =1; Female =0, but I need to do a Male tab, where Male =1, Female =0; and a Female tab, where Female =1, Male = 0. Also, let's say I have a Question (variable), "How often do you watch TV?", with answers: Never, Once a month, Once a week, Once a day, Once an hour, All the time. Do I need a tab for each answer? (i.e. TV(never), TV(once a month), etc.) My questions concerning media use actually have 12 answers...

Comment: @SimeonVasilev, For fields that are binary (male/female), you can just code them as 0/1 (where, 0 would mean 'male', for instance) -- instead of creating **two** additional fields like you mentioned. For categorical fields that have **more than two** levels, you can create a field for each level. A better alternative is to create an **ordinal** field (where applicable) -- for instance, in you **TV** example, you can create one field that contains 0 for 'Never', 1 'Once a day', 2 for 'Once a week', etc.

Comment: BTW, I am afraid this comment section is not intended for this type of *extended* conversation; you can consider the 'chat' section for such purpose.

Comment: Yes, I'd make sure to use it in the future. Thank you for your contribution, you have helped me A LOT.